# How to annotate interface property get and set with attributes in F#

Tags: f#, com, c#-to-f#

How to translate the following COM interface to F#? I cannot figure out how to annotate `get` and `set` of a property.

Plus, for COM interop, do I need to annotate both a property itself and its `get` with `DispId`?

```cs
[ComImport, TypeLibType((short)0x1040), Guid("F935DC23-1CF0-11D0-ADB9-00C04FD58A0B")]
private interface IWshShortcut
{
    [DispId(0)]
    string FullName { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0)] get; }
    [DispId(0x3e8)]
    string Arguments { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3e8)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3e8)] set; }
    [DispId(0x3ec)]
    string RelativePath { [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ec)] set; }
    [DispId(0x3ee)]
    int WindowStyle { [DispId(0x3ee)] get; [param: In] [DispId(0x3ee)] set; }
    [DispId(0x3ef)]
    string WorkingDirectory { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ef)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ef)] set; }
    [TypeLibFunc((short)0x40), DispId(0x7d0)]
    void Load([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string PathLink);
    [DispId(0x7d1)]
    void Save();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a correct, though not literal, translation:

```
[<ComImport; Guid("F935DC23-1CF0-11D0-ADB9-00C04FD58A0B"); TypeLibType(0x1040s)>]
type private IWshShortcut =
  [<DispId(0)>]
  abstract member FullName : [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)>] string with get

  [<DispId(0x3e8)>]
  abstract member Arguments : [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)>] string with get, set

  [<DispId(0x3ec)>]
  abstract member RelativePath : [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)>] string with set

  [<DispId(0x3ee)>]
  abstract member WindowStyle : int with get, set

  [<DispId(0x3ef)>]
  abstract member WorkingDirectory : [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)>] string with get, set

  [<DispId(0x7d0); TypeLibFunc(0x40s)>]
  abstract member Load : [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)>] PathLink:string -> unit

  [<DispId(0x7d1)>]
  abstract member Save : unit -> unit
```

As you found, you cannot add attributes to an abstract property's underlying getter/setter methods in F#, only to the property itself, but it doesn't matter for this particular interface:

- String properties with both `get` and `set` need the same `MarshalAs` for both anyway.
- [`In` is the default directionality for string parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77e6taeh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so specifying it would be redundant anyway.
- Applying `DispId` to the property getter as your C# code does is legal but pointless – while `DispId` can be applied to both methods and properties, and property getters and setters technically happen to be methods, the attribute only has an effect for the property itself.

N.b. because [the CLR marshals string parameters for COM methods as BStrs by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx#Anchor_7), we can omit all the `MarshalAs` directives as well and make this look a bit more trim (albeit less explicit):

```
[<ComImport; Guid("F935DC23-1CF0-11D0-ADB9-00C04FD58A0B"); TypeLibType(0x1040s)>]
type private IWshShortcut =
  [<DispId(0)>] abstract member FullName:string with get
  [<DispId(0x3e8)>] abstract member Arguments:string with get, set
  [<DispId(0x3ec)>] abstract member RelativePath:string with set
  [<DispId(0x3ee)>] abstract member WindowStyle:int with get, set
  [<DispId(0x3ef)>] abstract member WorkingDirectory:string with get, set
  [<DispId(0x7d0); TypeLibFunc(0x40s)>] abstract member Load : PathLink:string -> unit
  [<DispId(0x7d1)>] abstract member Save : unit -> unit
```

<sub>Of course, all of this applies to the C# implementation as well, so it can be similarly simplified:</sub>

```cs
[ComImport, Guid("F935DC23-1CF0-11D0-ADB9-00C04FD58A0B"), TypeLibType((short)0x1040)]
private interface IWshShortcut
{
    [DispId(0)] string FullName { get; }
    [DispId(0x3e8)] string Arguments { get; set; }
    [DispId(0x3ec)] string RelativePath { set; }
    [DispId(0x3ee)] int WindowStyle { get; set; }
    [DispId(0x3ef)] string WorkingDirectory { get; set; }
    [DispId(0x7d0), TypeLibFunc((short)0x40)] void Load(string PathLink);
    [DispId(0x7d1)] void Save();
}
```

Comment: Attributes **can** be applied to get and set separately (although here it doesn't matter)

Comment: @Sehnsucht : I struggled to find the correct syntax for that... Mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/properties-%5Bfsharp%5D) maybe ^^ ; silly example from actual context : `[<DispId (0x3e8)>] abstract member Arguments : string with get; 
[<DispId (0x3e9)>] abstract member Arguments : string with set`

Comment: @Sehnsucht : But where do you put `In` specifically (which is the one I struggled with)? It's unnecessary here, but if `[<In; Out>]` were needed I'd at least like to know how to do it. ;-]

Comment: @Sehnsucht : I just tested `[<DispId (0x3e8)>] abstract member Arguments : string with get; [<DispId (0x3e9)>] abstract member Arguments : string with set` and looked at the IL, and `DispId` was applied to the property (not the getter/setter) with the value 0x3e8 – no idea where 0x3e9 went. So while this syntax works, it in no way has the intended effect. :-[

Comment: seems that In/Out attribute aren't allowed for properties at all in C# aswell other attribute (like MarshalAs) work fine ; same with In for a method parameter (as expected). For DispId ; setting different values for the same attribute in getter and setter isn't exactly the right way to use it (and probably has the same "IL behaviour" in C#).

Comment: @Sehnsucht : That's missing my point, which is that while attributes can be applied to `get` and `set` separately _syntatically_, the attributes still apply to the property and not to the underlying getter/setter method. This is all that's relevant to the question and is what I meant to say in the answer – I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @Sehnsucht : And so I don't ignore the rest of your comment..: ;-] "*seems that In/Out attribute aren't allowed for properties at all in C#*" They are valid on the underlying getter/setter method (a property `int Foo { get; set; }` looks like `int get_Foo()` and `void set_Foo(int value)` in IL). "*For DispId ; setting different values for the same attribute in getter and setter isn't exactly the right way to use it*" I said exactly this in the answer already. "*and probably has the same "IL behaviour" in C#*" No, as shown in the question the attributes do apply to the underlying getter/setter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117791/discussion-between-sehnsucht-and-ildjarn).

Comment: Despite the documentation, for a concrete property `[<A>]member __.P with get() = ...` puts the attribute on the property, not the getter.  However, `member __.P with [<A>] get ... and [<B>] set ...` appears to do the desired thing.  I can't find any analog for an abstract property, though.  It's probably worth filing a bug on the compiler and/or documentation repos.

Comment: @kvb : That confirms my thoughts exactly, thanks Keith. My reading of the language spec leads me to believe there's no grammar for the abstract case, so it wouldn't be a compiler bug – a reasonable feature request, though!

Comment: Thanks, so I take that in F# there is not way to annotate get/set as in the C# sample. But for this particular scenario annotations are excessive anyways. 
 
Btw it works even if I remove DispId at all. I wonder if there are any perf implications (not critical for my case).